# Run multiple functions on single videostream multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Hey I am trying to run different face detection models simultaneously. I am using opencv library to open Video Stream and created different process objects for different face detection models.  When I run the program the first method is running successfully  but second method exits with an error that can't receive frame.

The major challenge is the while loop for reading the capture source(cap) which makes it different from the question posted on stackoverflow before

The code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import dlib
from multiprocessing import Process

def haar_cascade():
    while True:
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('input',frame)
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
        classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface2.xml')
        faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
        for result in faces:
            x, y, w, h = result
            x1, y1 = x + w, y + h
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
        cv2.imshow('harr-cascade',frame)


def dlib_hog():
    while True:
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
        detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector(gray, 1) # result
        #to draw faces on image
        for result in faces:
            x = result.left()
            y = result.top()
            x1 = result.right()
            y1 = result.bottom()
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
        cv2.imshow('dlib-hog',frame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()
    harrProcess=Process(target=haar_cascade)
    harrProcess.start()
    dlibProcess=Process(target=dlib_hog)
    dlibProcess.start()

# When everything done, release the capture
harrProcess.join()
dlibProcess.join()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I create a multiprocessing model that read source from single source and perform independent operation?

Comment: you need a single-producer, multiple-consumer pattern. check out this old code I wrote: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40 it was designed to be multi-consumer (using `notify_all`)

Answer (score 0):

I have made various attempts:

1. I tried using multiprocessing with a producer process and two consumer processes. The frame created by the producer must be converted to a shared-memory array and then converted back to a `numpy` array when retrieved by a consumer. There is sufficient overhead in these operations that I was finding that frames were being lost.
2. I tried using multithreading with a producer thread and two consumer threads. This has less overhead with regards to passing frames from the producer and consumer. The problem, of course, with multithreading is that due to contention for the Global Interpreter Lock, any CPU-intensive processing required by a consumer cannot be run in parallel with CPU-intensive processing required by the other consumer and could even cause the producer to miss frames. Unfortunately, I don't know if when using a camera for input whether there is a way to detect missed frames on the part of the producer. To remediate these problems I pass a multiprocessing pool to the consumer threads to which they can submit tasks that perform the CPU-intensive processing on the frames. Here, too, there is sufficient overhead in passing frames from one process to another and frames are lost.
3. As in bullet point 2 above, I use multithreading but instead of submitting CPU-intensive work to the multiprocessing pool, I perform it within the consumer thread. This seems to cause fewer missed frames for the consumer. But I can't tell if it is causing the producer now to miss frames it would not otherwise miss. So using a multiprocessing pool for doing the CPU-intensive work seems to be the wiser approach. Of course, if your CPU is fast enough, neither the consumer not producer should miss frames. But option 1 (see second code example), i.e. using just multiprocessing, is probably best.

In the following demos, since I don't have access to your XML file, I have dummied out the processing for one of your consumers. You terminate the program by just hitting the enter key:

**Using Multithreading**

Set `USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION = False` to perform CPU-intensive processing by direct call instead of submitting the work to a multiprocessing pool:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import multiprocessing
import cv2
import dlib

USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION = True

class Producer:
    def __init__(self):

        # Create shared memory version of a numpy array:
        self._frame = None

        self._condition = threading.Condition()

        self._running = True

        # The latest frame number retrieved
        self._latest_frame_number = 0

    def run(self, cap):
        while self._running:
            ret, self._frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                self._running = False
            else:
                self._latest_frame_number += 1
            with self._condition:
                self._condition.notify_all()

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False

    def get_frame(self, sequence_number):
        with self._condition:
            # We block until we find a frame sequence number >= sequence_number.
            self._condition.wait_for(lambda: not self._running or self._latest_frame_number >= sequence_number)
        # Even after the stop method has been called and we are no longer running,
        # there could still be an unprocessed frame. But when we are called again, the current
        # frame number will be < the expected frame number:
        return (self._latest_frame_number, None if self._latest_frame_number < sequence_number else self._frame)

def process_haar_cascade(frame):
    classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface2.xml')
    faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
    for result in faces:
        x, y, w, h = result
        x1, y1 = x + w, y + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return frame

def haar_cascade(producer, pool):
    last_sequence_number = 0

    while True:
        expected = last_sequence_number + 1
        sequence_number, frame = producer.get_frame(expected)
        if frame is None:
            break

        cv2.waitKey(1) # allow window to update
        if sequence_number != expected:
            print(f'haar_cascade missed frames {expected} to {sequence_number-1}', flush=True)
        last_sequence_number = sequence_number

        cv2.imshow('input', frame) # Unmodified frame

        # Since I don't have required xml file, just skip processing:
        """
        if USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION:
            frame = pool.apply(process_haar_cascade, args=(frame,))
        else:
            frame = process_haar_cascade(frame)
        """
        cv2.imshow('harr-cascade', frame)


def process_dlib_hog(frame):
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector(gray, 1) # result
    #to draw faces on image
    for result in faces:
        x = result.left()
        y = result.top()
        x1 = result.right()
        y1 = result.bottom()
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return frame

def dlib_hog(producer, pool):
    last_sequence_number = 0

    while True:
        expected = last_sequence_number + 1
        sequence_number, frame = producer.get_frame(expected)
        if frame is None:
            break

        cv2.waitKey(1) # allow window to update
        if sequence_number != expected:
            print(f'dlib_hog missed frames {expected} to {sequence_number-1}', flush=True)
        last_sequence_number = sequence_number

        if USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION:
            frame = pool.apply(process_dlib_hog, args=(frame,))
        else:
            frame = process_dlib_hog(frame)
        cv2.imshow('dlib-hog', frame)

def main():
    producer = Producer()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2) if USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION else None
    # Pass pool for CPU-Intensive work:
    consumer1_thread = threading.Thread(target=haar_cascade, args=(producer, pool))
    consumer1_thread.start()
    consumer2_thread = threading.Thread(target=dlib_hog, args=(producer, pool))
    consumer2_thread.start()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    producer_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer.run, args=(cap,))
    producer_thread.start()

    input('Hit enter to terminate:\n')
    producer.stop()
    producer_thread.join()
    consumer1_thread.join()
    consumer2_thread.join()

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    if USE_POOL_FOR_COMPUTATION:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Using Multiprocessing**

<s>The `multiprocessing.RawArray` that is used to hold the sharable frame must be allocated before the consumer process is run so that all processes have access to this array. This requires knowing in advance how large an array to create:</s>

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib


class Producer:
    def __init__(self):
        # Discover how large a framesize is by getting the first frame
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            self._shape = frame.shape
            frame_size = self._shape[0] * self._shape[1] * self._shape[2]
            self._shared_array = multiprocessing.RawArray(ctypes.c_ubyte, frame_size)
        else:
            self._arr = None
        cap.release()

        self._condition = multiprocessing.Condition()

        self._running = multiprocessing.RawValue('i', 1)

        # The latest frame number retrieved
        self._latest_frame_number = multiprocessing.RawValue('i', 0)

        self._lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while self._running.value:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                self._running.value = 0
                with self._condition:
                    self._condition.notify_all()
                cap.release()
                break

            with self._lock:
                self._latest_frame_number.value += 1

                # np array to shared_array
                temp = np.frombuffer(self._shared_array, dtype=frame.dtype)
                temp[:] = frame.flatten(order='C')

            with self._condition:
                self._condition.notify_all()


    def stop(self):
        self._running.value = 0


    def get_frame(self, sequence_number):
        with self._condition:
            # We block until we find a frame sequence number >= sequence_number.
            self._condition.wait_for(lambda: not self._running.value or self._latest_frame_number.value >= sequence_number)
        # Even after the stop method has been called and we are no longer running,
        # there could still be an unprocessed frame. But when we are called again, the current
        # frame number will be < the expected frame number:
        if self._latest_frame_number.value < sequence_number:
            return (self._latest_frame_number.value, None)

        with self._lock:
        # Convert to np array:
            return  self._latest_frame_number.value, np.ctypeslib.as_array(self._shared_array).reshape(self._shape)

def process_haar_cascade(frame):
    classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface2.xml')
    faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
    for result in faces:
        x, y, w, h = result
        x1, y1 = x + w, y + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return frame

def haar_cascade(producer):
    last_sequence_number = 0

    while True:
        expected = last_sequence_number + 1
        sequence_number, frame = producer.get_frame(expected)
        if frame is None:
            break

        cv2.waitKey(1) # allow window to update
        if sequence_number != expected:
            print(f'haar_cascade missed frames {expected} to {sequence_number-1}', flush=True)
        last_sequence_number = sequence_number

        cv2.imshow('input', frame) # Unmodified frame
        # Since I don't have required xml file, just skip processing:
        #frame = process_haar_cascade(frame)
        cv2.imshow('harr-cascade', frame)


def process_dlib_hog(frame):
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector(gray, 1) # result
    #to draw faces on image
    for result in faces:
        x = result.left()
        y = result.top()
        x1 = result.right()
        y1 = result.bottom()
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return frame

def dlib_hog(producer):
    last_sequence_number = 0

    while True:
        expected = last_sequence_number + 1
        sequence_number, frame = producer.get_frame(expected)
        if frame is None:
            break

        cv2.waitKey(1) # allow window to update
        if sequence_number != expected:
            print(f'dlib_hog missed frames {expected} to {sequence_number-1}', flush=True)
        last_sequence_number = sequence_number

        frame = process_dlib_hog(frame)
        cv2.imshow('dlib-hog', frame)

def main():
    producer = Producer()

    # Pass pool for CPU-Intensive work:
    consumer1_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=haar_cascade, args=(producer,))
    consumer1_process.start()
    consumer2_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=dlib_hog, args=(producer,))
    consumer2_process.start()

    producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.run)
    producer_process.start()

    input('Hit enter to terminate:\n')
    producer.stop()
    producer_process.join()
    consumer1_process.join()
    consumer2_process.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```